# Some Users Suddenly Unable to Login via ADFS SSO

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, single-sign-on, adfs

We have an ASP.NET 4.5.2 Web Forms application with a multi-tenant environment with some clients using WS-Fed ADFS for SSO.

However, starting on September 8, 2020 we've had reports from a growing handful of users (from a few different clients) out of about 20,000 users or so that, after years with no issues, they are unable to login anymore.  Our clients are reporting the issue with Chrome, but I am able to replicate in Chrome and Edge, and Firefox but only in Private Mode. Firefox seems (so far) to be working if not in Private Mode.  Coincidentally, September 8, 2020 also just happens to be when a Google Chrome update occurred.

We've implemented some heavy login tracking and it appears that, once the user signs into their ADFS and is sent back to our server, our server is not detecting it as a response from their ADFS server (we use `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.Contains(strIssuer)`) and just presents them with an AD Login button as if they just arrived at the page for the first time.

I'm wondering if this has anything to do with `SameSite` changes that appear to be occurring with the browsers.

Has anyone experienced anything like this and is able to point me in the right direction?

If there is any further information I can add please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

After even more digging in and more logging we found that the issue appeared to be that `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri` no longer always contained the clients full Issuer (e.g., `https://adfs.site.tld/adfs/ls`) and sometimes was only `https://adfs.site.tld`.

To fix, we no longer look for the complete Issuer in the `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri` and instead look only for the `UriPartial.Authority` value like so:

`Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(new Uri(strIssuer).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority))` where `strIssuer` is `https://adfs.site.tld/adfs/ls`.

We've so far had 100% successful logins of the users that previously experienced the problem since this small change was made.

Hopefully this is useful to someone in the future.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue is caused by the recent changes in the behaviour in Chrome which are meant to improve privacy.

It is explained here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default

It breaks some features which rely on the referrer string sent by the browser, even Microsoft had that issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4547705/authentication-loop-between-msft-sts-microsoft-com-adfs-and-owa-in-exc

What you did to fix the problem seems to be the right approach according to Google, other options are also explained in the above link.